# How to choose which hierarchical clustering algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

If I have given with a data set how do I determine which hierarchical clustering algorithm I should use? whether to use **single, complete or average** linkage?

what are the criteria that I need to consider before selecting?

Answer (score 3):

Choose what **gives the best results on your data**.

Try all of them. Then **evaluate, evaluate, evaluate**. Don't assume that some mathematical measure will tell you what to do, this is very data specific, and ***usefulness* cannot be captured by mathematics**.